# how can we reuse the google map object and not create in everytime the activity is called

Tags: android, maps

I want that the map object once created should be reused and not created again and again because when ever the `onCreate()` of `support manager` gets called I feel its a new instance, that I need to avoid so can anyone please help me on this ?

Sharing the code I am using:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;      


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int checkGooglePlayServices = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        if (checkGooglePlayServices != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(checkGooglePlayServices)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(checkGooglePlayServices,
                        this,
                        0).show();


            } else
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Please check your Google Play Services in order to run this app",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gmap);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();


}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
    // map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).setRetainInstance(true);
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.

        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                    View customMarkerView = null;
                    try {
                        customMarkerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.view_custom_marker, null);
                        TextView titleView = (TextView) customMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.title);

                        customMarkerView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        customMarkerView.layout(0, 0, customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight());
                        customMarkerView.buildDrawingCache();


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return customMarkerView;
                }
            });
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}


private void setUpMap() {
    try {
        int ZoomLevel = 9;
        int animateZoomLevel = 7;
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(myvehicleInfo.getLatitude());
        double log = Double.parseDouble(myvehicleInfo.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, log)));

        String type = Utility.getDefaultMap(GMapActivity.this);
        switch (type) {
            case "Normal":
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                break;
            case "Hybrid":
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                break;
            case "Satellite":
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                break;
            case "Terrain":
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                break;
        }


        LatLng longlat = new LatLng(lat, log);

        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        builder.include(longlat);



        final CameraPosition cameraPosition1 = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(longlat)
                .zoom(ZoomLevel + animateZoomLevel)
                .tilt(45)
                .build();

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(longlat, ZoomLevel));

        try {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition1)
                    , 2500,
                    new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            double lat = Double.parseDouble(myvehicleInfo.getLatitude());
                            double log = Double.parseDouble(myvehicleInfo.getLongitude());
                            LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, log);
                            MarkerOptions axesTrackMarker = null;

                            if (myvehicleInfo.getLocation().isEmpty()) {
                                axesTrackMarker = new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(ll)
                                        .title(myvehicleInfo.getVehicleName());
                            } else {
                                axesTrackMarker = new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(ll)/*
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                                .fromBitmap(
                                                        getMarkerBitmapFromView(
                                                                myvehicleInfo.getVehicleName(),
                                                                myvehicleInfo.getLocation())
                                                        ))*/;


                            }

                            mMap.addMarker(axesTrackMarker).showInfoWindow();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // do something
                        }
                    }
            );

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // }
        //});
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: oncreate call just once when activity create after that On resume called when you come from back ground.

Comment: that means its using the previous object only and not creating a new instance everytime ?

Comment: no It create when if it get object null. see you have check inside on resume if(map==null) then it create else not. first time when your activity created that time its null so it create after that you come again in on resume it check if object null then only it create

Comment: You want `mMap` instance to be **created** only once? or **initialized** only once?